# I/O error on secondary SSD

Tags: io

I had an I/O error on an ssd (sda) and somehow ended up *thankfully* backing my files up and reinstalling ubuntu on another ssd (nvme0n1), though, problem is, now with the first ssd (sda) broken i can't reset it, i tried DD to erase the first few megabytes of that ssd but gparted still reports an Input Output error

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

if it matters, this is on a Dell laptop, and the first ssd (sda) came in the laptop, the second did not